# Insert photo from Form (Office 2007)

Tags: vba, excel, templates

After this code

```
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Range("Q3:S5").Select
        MyRange = Selection.Address

        PicLocation = UserForm1.txtImage

        If PicLocation <> "False" Then
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicLocation).Select
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            If .Width > .Height Then
                .Width = Range(MyRange).Width
                If .Height > Range(MyRange).Height Then .Height = Range(MyRange).Height
            Else
                .Height = Range(MyRange).Height
                If .Width > Range(MyRange).Width Then .Width = Range(MyRange).Width
            End If
        End With

        With Selection
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            .PrintObject = True
        End With

End With
```

`

My image isn't in the merged cell I want to be ("Q3:S5").

But in the office 2010 this code is just fine. 
Unfortunately, I need to run in Office 2007.

[imageIssue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmp454xhpuybtq9/ImageIssue.jpg?dl=0)

Sorry for external link, but I don't have reputation to upload an image.

Also, I want image to be in "Middle alignment".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this version of the code works. Change the file name to how you want it.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Set myRng = Range("Q3:S5")
    Set mypict = myRng.Parent.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\9-29-2015 4-21-06 AM.jpg")
    mypict.Top = myRng.Top
    mypict.Width = myRng.Width
    mypict.Height = myRng.Height
    mypict.Left = myRng.Left
    mypict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End Sub
```